# FlexBuilder to FDT Migration

Tags: actionscript-3, autocomplete, migration, flexbuilder, fdt

I'm new to FDT and I'd like to move some (actionscript)projects from FlexBuilder to FDT.

I've noticed FDT can read .actionscriptProperties from FlexBuilder, so just setting the workspace to my FlexBuilder workspace got the projects, the current one open, the rest of them closed which is great.

I got a an error on the way:

"Error opening the editor.
No editor descriptor for id com.adobe.flexbuilder.editors.actionscript.ActionScriptEditor"

which makes sense...I the last editor used was the as editor from flexbuilder, which isn't present in fdt...no biggie here.

My problem is that I don't get the FDT autocomplete working, not even for the default AS3 classes( Sprite, TextField, etc. )

I've tried right clicking the project then Flash Project > Remove Flash Nature
then Flash Project > Add Flash Nature again...but it didn't seem to do anything.
I don't even know what it does. I'm guessing it's telling FDT to treat this project as CS3 or Flex compiled project.

I've also imported a project from SVN in FDT and no autocomplete.

So, how do I get the great FDT auto-completion for a FlexBuilder Actionscript Project opened in FDT ?

Comment: what would be great is an import / export feature that works between FDT, FlashBuilder and FlashDevelop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I must be satisfied with the answer that there is no easy answer. The is no lazy-man's option of just opening a flexproject in fdt just like that and having everything working.

So I guess the answer would be using Export/Import.

Answer (score 1):

The currect version of FDT ships with an "Flex project importer". In the flash explorer under "Import -> Import Flex Builder 3 Projects".

Comment: Cool, I'll try that again. Are class paths preserved from the imported project ? Does auto complete work now ?